# Calculate the top 25% users who have the score

Tags: mysql

I have this query which i am trying to get the top 25% score of the users

but running this i am getting error

```
SELECT
tblcontact_platform.ContactPlatformID,
tblcontact_platform.ContactID,
tblcontact_platform.PlatformID,
tblcontact_platform.Followers,
tblcontact_platform.Score_Responsiveness,
tblcontact_platform.Score_Responsiveness_UpdatedDateTime,
tblcontact_platform.CreatedDateTime,
tblcontact.ContactID,
tblcontact.ContactHandle,
tblcontact.LastName,
tblcontact.FirstName,
PERCENT_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY tblcontact.Score_Responsiveness) PercentileRank
FROM
tblcontact_platform inner join tblcontact on tblcontact.contactid = tblcontact_platform.contactid 

where tblcontact_platform.contactid in (100,101,103)
```

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(ORDER BY tblcontact.Score_Responsiveness) PercentileRank FROM tblcontact_plat' at line 13

I am on **mysql 5.7.12** or **mariaDB 10.1**

Comment: both versions **don't** have window functions so you can't use them

Comment: ok, then how can i fix the query above i have, i am stuck on this section

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating percentile rank in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057027/calculating-percentile-rank-in-mysql)

Comment: Well, you could upgrade.

Comment: if i could upgrade, i should not have asked the question itself